# How to print bootstrap modal contents

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to print the contents of a react-bootstrap modal using window.print(), but the modal gets cut off. Is there a way to print the full modal so that it doesn't get cut off?

Seems so simple but I have not found a solution

Answer (score 0):

```css
@media print{
 .modal-dialog {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

Can you try to add this to your CSS? Its most likely a print issue.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately. It still cuts off the contents of the modal.